# the total value of a set of text fields cant be displayed/computed - angular js html php

Tags: php, html, angularjs, forms

i have a simple form that has "total" fields and another overall total field (this is the sum of all the "total" fields).

the "total" fields are computed from the values of qty and unitcost fields, that is qty0 * unitcost0= total0, qty1 * unitcost1 = total1, and so on.. please note that qty and amt are from the database

i want the overall total to be computed like total0+total1+ total2.....and so on on real time.

here is my code (sorry if this code is messy for some but im just a beginner in programming )
my ng-app is in the body tag and my ng-controller is in a div

```
<?php
        echo '
           <form name="editpo" id="editpo" method="post" action="poeditprocess.php">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="1">Stock No.</th>
                    <th colspan="1"> Unit </th>
                    <th colspan="5">Description</th>
                    <th colspan="1">Quantity</td>
                    <th colspan="1">Unit Cost</th>
                    <th colspan="1">Amount</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table id="items">';


            //print the item desc, unit, qty and unit cost 
            $ctr02 = 1;
            $tamt = 0;

            for ($i=0; $i < $ctritem; $i++)
            {
                $amt = $qty[$i] * $unitc[$i];
                $tamt = $tamt + $amt;

                $unitc[$i] = number_format($unitc[$i], 2, '.', ',');
                $amt = number_format($amt, 2, '.', ',');
                //initialize the qty and unitcost with the values fro db                
                echo '<tr ng-init="qty'.$i.'='.$qty[$i].'; cost'.$i.'='.$unitc[$i].';">';
                                echo "
                                            <td id='amt'>".$ctr02."</td>
                                            <td> <input type='text' name='unit[".$i."]' value='".$poitemunit[$i]."' required/></td>
                                            <td colspan='3'><textarea rows='2' name='desc[".$i."]' required>".$poitemdesc[$i]."</textarea></td>";
                                echo '
                                            <td><input type="number" name="qty'.$i.'"  id="qty'.$i.'" min="0" max="10000" ng-model="qty'.$i.'" required /></td>
                                            <td><input type="number" name="unitcost" ng-model ="cost'.$i.'" step="any" min="0" required /></td>

                                            <td><input type="text" name="amt'.$i.'" id="amt'.$i.'" step="any" value="{{(qty'.$i.' * cost'.$i.') | currency : \'P \' : 2}}" disabled/></td>

                                        </tr>';

                            $ctr02++;
                            }
                            echo "
                        </table>";

                    echo "  <table>";
            //this is the overall total
                    echo '<td><input type="text" name="tamt" id="tamt" value="{{(';
                                $x=0;
                                while($x<=$ctritem){
                                echo '(qty'.$x.' * cost'.$x.')';
                                    if($x<$ctritem){
                                    echo '+';
                                    }
                                $x++;

                                }

                    echo ')| currency : \'Php \' : 2}}" disabled/></td>
                            </tr>';

                    echo "</table> 
                    </form>";
                    ?>
```

ctritem is the no. of items that are in the list. i used for loop to print all the items that are to be totalled. and then used while loop to get the sum of the total.

the total is working fine. but the overall total is not working at all
I dont know whats wrong with this since i had this same code working smoothly on the other page. any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Leilo thanks for the answer, i appreciate it so much. however, i still cant make it work. but after how many tries, i thought i'll rewrite the whole snippet of code for the grand total and then it worked. (insert big laugh here cause i dont really know what's wrong in the first code)

so for the benefit of all who will encounter the same problem as mine (or as closely related to my problem) here is the code:

```
//this is the overall total
                    echo '<td><input type="text" name="tamt" id="tamt" value="{{';
                        $ctrt = 0;      
                        while ($ctrt<$i)
                        {
                            echo'(qty'.$ctrt.' * cost'.$ctrt++.')';
                            if($ctrt<$i){
                                echo '+';
                            }

                        }   

                    echo '| currency : \'Php \' : 2}}" disabled/></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
    <input type="text" name="amt'.$i.'" id="amt'.$i.'" step="any" 
    value="{{(qty'.$i.' * cost'.$i.') | currency : \'P \' : 2}}" 
    disabled/>
</td>
```

Declare a variable

```
total$i = qty$i * cost$i
```

inside the for loop and change the previoius line to 
    
        
    
Then outside the for loop declare

```
$grandtotal = 0
```

and inside the for loop add $total$i to $grandtotal whith:

```
$grandtotal += $total$i;
```